# Maven plugin that allows to add entries to settings.xml?

Tags: maven, settings

I have private Maven repository (Nexus2) that requires a fixed username and password even for reading it.

I am now trying to find an easy way to make this repository accessible by all developers. My first attempt was to define the repository in the parent project's `pom.xml` (which is only accessible for developers from the SCM) -  which does not work as there is no way to specify username and password.

Therefore I have to edit the user specific `settings.xml`.

**Is there a Maven plugin available that allows me to add specific entries to the `settings.xml` upon execution?**

Comment: Simple answer no. Apart from that where should the configuration for the appropriate plugin (if such would exist) comming from? So yes private things like password / username have to be done by the dev...

Comment: Does this mean there is no other way than editing the `settings.xml` by hand? Even if we are talking about developers I would not call this user friendly. May be there is a way to modify settings via `mvn` command-line?

Comment: No there is no such way. How often do you need to do that? Once you make the initial setup and maybe if your password changes...If you don't like it than implement such things..Maven is an open source project...